# C# JSON deserialize to array with no name

Tags: c#, arrays, json, serialization

How can I deserialize in C# something like this:

```
{
  'list': [
    ['083', 'user', 7, 14, 45, 0],
    ['38', 'Mike', 8, 52, 85, 3],
    ['b43', 'BusStop', 23, 86, 17, 2]
  ],
  'Weather': None
}
```

Comment: besides the fact that jour "json" is _invalid_: what have you ***tried yourself*** so far? what problems did you encounter? what have you researched?

please also read [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `list List<List<string>> {get;set;}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Charlieface in the comments, `List<List<string>>` is what you're looking for.

```
public class Details
{
    public List<List<string>> List { get; set; }
    public string Weather { get; set; }
}
```

Then use `JsonConvert` to deserialize.

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Details>(str);
```

Comment: `7, 14, 45, 0` are not strings, so depended on serializer  this can fail.

Comment: @GuruStron Oh, missed that

Comment: @GuruStron not strings, but still works with no fail.